# Repeat ng-template with ng-content as body (create copy of ng-content)

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, transclusion

I am creating an option to add custom columns to a PrimeNg table. The reason I want to create this is because I am offering a default table with a lot of configuration options already set.

The problem I am running into is that I cannot seem to be able to repeat an `ng-template` component multiple times.

---

**My versions**

- Angular `7.2.12`
- Primeng `7.1.0`
- @angular/animations `7.2.12`

---

**What do I want to achieve**

I want to create a wrapper that simplifies column creation and removes the need for creating multiple templates within the table body.

Example what I want to simplify:

```
<table>
 <!-- Row 1 -->
 <ng-template #header><th>edit></th></ng-template>
 <ng-template #content><button>edit></button></ng-template>

 <!-- Row 2 -->
 <ng-template #header><th>delete></th></ng-template>
 <ng-template #content><button>delete></button></ng-template>
</table>
```

I want to simplify this to:

```
<table>
  <!-- Row 1 -->
  <custom-column>
    <th header>edit></th>
    <button>edit></button>
  </custom-column>

  <!-- Row 2 -->
  <custom-column>
    <th header>delete></th>
    <button>delete></button>
  </custom-column>
</table>
```

I've almost got this working in this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dyuamf)

---

**The problem**

The problem I am now facing is that I need to repeat the content template for every row in the table, so that there is an edit and a delete button for every row. But with this setup the buttons are only shown on the last row (I think this is because the `ng-content` only transcludes once?).

Is it possible what I am trying to achieve and if so, how should I change my code?

Comment: Actually it transcludes for every iteration ,(as you can see the binding comments), but its getting projected only for the last iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Since the `ng-content` component does not support projecting the same content multiple times ([here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13894) and [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9173)) I needed to switch to injecting templates into the table component.

Inspired by the way Primeng solves this problem (by creating a directive that holds the template):

```
@Directive({ selector: '[pTemplate]' })
export class PrimeTemplate {

  @Input() type: string;

  @Input('pTemplate') name: string;

  constructor(public template: TemplateRef<any>) { }

  getType(): string {
    return this.name;
  }
}
```

Usage: `<ng-template pTemplate="header"></ng-template`

They are creating a template and getting a reference to that template within the table component. A template can be reused unlimited times, thus solving the projection problem.

---

Because I wanted to keep flexibility, but wanted to avoid using string comparison (note the 'name' property) and the need to extract the right templates from the `querylist` I ended up with creating 2 directives, that can be used as follows (kind of the same as example my first attempt, but a better implementation):

```
<ng-container>
  <ng-template appColHeader>Delete</ng-template>
  <ng-template appColContent><button>Not here!</button></ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

The full implementation of this code can be found is this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dmzc6e).